# tools:showIn="navigation_view" not working

Tags: java, android, android-developer-api

When i append tools:showIn="navigation_view" to my code it's not showing. But in video which i watched from Youtube this is working fine. What is the problem? Also I can't add library called

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_main_home"
            android:title="@string/home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_timetable"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_subject_timetable"
            android:title="@string/timetable" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_ogrnot"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_ogrnot"
            android:title="@string/ogrnot" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_yemek_menu"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_yemek_menu"
            android:title="@string/yemek_menu" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_homework"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_homework"
            android:title="@string/homework" />
    </group>
    <item android:title="@string/optional">
        <menu>
            <item 
                android:id="@+id/nav_to_do_list"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_to_do_list"
                android:title="@string/to_do_list" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
                android:title="@string/logout" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my code. The first thing I did was to delete my already created menu file (Android resource file) and start the process from the top. 
Secondly, after creating the menu resource file, on a new line, after typing `(tool:)`, press alt+enter to add this automatically for you... `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"...` Then you can go ahead to type in `tools:showIn="....."`.

To know if this works, in line of code in `tools:showIn`, when typing the name in the quotes, just type `"na'...` if there are other popups or suggestions, then you're good to go.

Hope this helps.